# Apache Tomcat random session number generator issue Ubuntu

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, ubuntu, digital-ocean

I have just finished a 7 hour long quest for solution solution of (*should have been*) non-existent problem.

This ***could*** be only DigitalOcean problem since I did not have it on my local development server, but just in case, I will try to prevent anyone from loosing time like I did.

What I did:

- Created DigitalOcean droplet
- Installed Oracle java ([link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu-with-apt-get))
- Installed Tomcat7 ([link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-7-on-ubuntu-14-04-via-apt-get))

Tomcat was working with absolutely no flaw. And then I have restarted tomcat7

```
service tomcat7 restart
```

And a simple "It works!" page took forever to load.
catalina.out seemed normal but... page had never loaded. So, why would tomcat not work out of the box with vanilla settings!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution on [this blog](http://blog.justinmiranda.com/2014/05/tomcat-7052-stalls-during-startup.html)

```
I just needed to add the following system property to Tomcat's startup routine.
-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
```

To me it looks like default tomcat package is packaged wrongly.